# List iteration in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i have a list with data like:

```
{ 
  State: 'Florida',
  Temperature: 83,
}
    { 
  State: 'Florida',
  Temperature: 82,
}
{ 
  State: 'Florida',
  Temperature: 79,
}
{ 
  State: 'Nevada',
  Temperature: 96,
}
{ 
  State: 'Nevada',
  Temperature: 93,
}
```

and so on

List are sorted in alphabetical order by state and from highest to lowest temp in each state.
How to iterate through this list to find the highest temp for each state?

Try this, but still dont work:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/weather', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var data = db.collection('data');

    var cursor = data.find({});

    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(doc == null) {
            return db.close();
        }
        var maxTemp = data.reduce(function(a,b) {
            return Math.max(a.Temperature, b.Temperature);
        });
        console.dir(maxTemp);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this list a JSON type data?

Comment: yes, im using mongoDB currently

Comment: That's not actually valid JSON nor is it an array, perhaps double check the output and paste it verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using a loop, assuming you have a valid array containing the objects.
After `maxTemps` is populated, it would look like something like this:

```
{ Florida=83, Nevada=96}
```

Here's the code:

```
var maxTemps = {};
    data = [{ 
        State: 'Florida',
        Temperature: 83,
    },
    { 
        State: 'Florida',
        Temperature: 82,
    },
    { 
        State: 'Florida',
        Temperature: 79,
    },
    { 
        State: 'Nevada',
        Temperature: 96,
    },
    { 
        State: 'Nevada',
        Temperature: 93,
    }];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    dataset = data[i];
    if(maxTemps[dataset.State]) {
        maxTemps[dataset.State] = Math.max(dataset.Temperature, maxTemps[dataset.State])
    } else {
        maxTemps[dataset.State] = dataset.Temperature;
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't care too much about the order of the array itself, you can sort in descending order by temperature and use the first element to get your max temp.

```
data.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.Temperature < b.Temperature;
});
console.log(data[0].Temperature);
```

Alternatively, as suggested, using reduce, but this function is not supported by IE8 without a polyfill.

```
var maxTemp = data.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return Math.max(a.Temperature, b.Temperature);
});
console.log(maxTemp);
```

Comment: i thinks reduce would be better :)))

Comment: @bitsMix Added a version using the `Array.reduce` function. :)

Comment: It works but when I try to assign variable to my db collection it's throw error "Object <#Collection> has no method 'reduce'" (i add code above)

Answer (score 0):

Create an object.

```
var obj = {};
```

For each object in the array, if the object doesn't have a key corresponding to the name of the state, add one and set the content to an empty array. Then push in the temperature.

```
arr.forEach(function (el) {
  if (!obj[el.State]) obj[el.State] = [];
  obj[el.State].push(el.Temperature);
});
```

Finally, loop over the object and use `Math.max.apply` to find the maximum value in the array:

```
for (var k in obj) {
  console.log(k + ': ' + Math.max.apply(null, obj[k])); // Florida: 83, Nevada: 96.
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A92BK/4/).

Answer (score 0):

1. the data you pasted is not a valid JSON.
2. the code below works in `node.js`:

---

```
var temperatureHistory = [{ 
  State: 'Florida',
  Temperature: 83,
},
{ 
  State: 'Florida',
  Temperature: 82,
},
{ 
  State: 'Florida',
  Temperature: 79,
},
{ 
  State: 'Nevada',
  Temperature: 96,
},
{ 
  State: 'Nevada',
  Temperature: 93,
}];


var max = temperatureHistory.reduce(function (topTemp, history) {
   if (history.Temperature > topTemp[history.State] || -99999) {
     topTemp[history.State] = history.Temperature;
   }
   return topTemp;
}, {});

console.log(max);
```

if you wanna support some old browser, i suggest [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: I think OP was looking for the highest temp for each state.